# Opening apps for corresponding file type

Tags: ios, swift, file-manager, file-mapping

How to open file with associated application when clicked in ios using swift? The file type can be anything like .pdf, .html, .png, .mp4 in swift? 
How do I open the default file manager app in iphone using swift and import the selected file?

Comment: A given file type can be opened by many different applications, not just one.

Comment: then use uiwebview

Comment: @rmaddy if a file can be opened by many application then it show the list of apps that can open the file type

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik How exactly should I use uiwebview to achieve this?